# Why this function does point to itself with a offset of 1?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, stm32, ld

I'm trying to write a bare metal blink program for a Nucleo-64 Stm32F401re board using C.
However while starting debugging for errors (it didn't blink yet) I found an odd adress for which I found no explanation. This is the output of the relevant part of the disassembly:

```
    blink.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <isr_vector_table>:
 8000000:       20018000        andcs   r8, r1, r0
 8000004:       08000009        stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <Reset_Handler>:
 8000008:       b480            push    {r7}
 800000a:       af00            add     r7, sp, #0
 800000c:       bf00            nop
 800000e:       46bd            mov     sp, r7
 8000010:       bc80            pop     {r7}
 8000012:       4770            bx      lr

Disassembly of section .ARM.attributes:

00000000 <.ARM.attributes>:
   0:   00002d41        andeq   r2, r0, r1, asr #26
   4:   61656100        cmnvs   r5, r0, lsl #2
   8:   01006962        tsteq   r0, r2, ror #18
   c:   00000023        andeq   r0, r0, r3, lsr #32
  10:   2d453705        stclcs  7, cr3, [r5, #-20]      ; 0xffffffec
  14:   0d06004d        stceq   0, cr0, [r6, #-308]     ; 0xfffffecc
  18:   02094d07        andeq   r4, r9, #448    ; 0x1c0
  1c:   01140412        tsteq   r4, r2, lsl r4
  20:   03170115        tsteq   r7, #1073741829 ; 0x40000005
  24:   01190118        tsteq   r9, r8, lsl r1
  28:   061e011a                        ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x061e011a
  2c:   Address 0x0000002c is out of bounds.
```

The Reset_Handler function itself is on the right adress but by using its name as pointer in the code it points one adress further! Here is the corresponding code:

```
extern int _stack_top; // bigger Memory Adress
    
    void Reset_Handler (void);

    __attribute__((section(".isr_vector"))) int* isr_vector_table[] = {

        (int*)&_stack_top,
        (int*)Reset_Handler
    };

    void Reset_Handler (void) {
        
    }
```

And the Linker script I used which is basically the same used in most tutorials.

```
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-bigarm", "elf32-littlearm")
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512K
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 96K
}

    _stack_top = ORIGIN(SRAM)+LENGTH(SRAM);

SECTIONS
{

    
    
    
    


    .text : 
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);   
        *(.isr_vector)
        *(.text*)
        *(.glue_7)
        *(.glue_7t)
        *(.eh_frame)
        KEEP(*(.init))
        KEEP(*(.fini))
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    .rodata :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);   
        *(.rodata*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > FLASH

    .ARM.extab :
        {
            *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    } >FLASH

    .ARM :
     {
            __exidx_start = .;
            *(.ARM.exidx*)
            __exidx_end = .;
     } >FLASH



    .preinit_array :
    {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    } >FLASH

    .init_array :
    {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    } >FLASH

    .fini_array :
    {   
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    } >FLASH



    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

    .data :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sdata = .;
        *(.data*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _edata = .;
    } > SRAM AT > FLASH

    .bss :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sbss = .;
        __bss_start__ = _sbss;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = .;
        __bss_end__ = _ebss;
    } > SRAM

    /DISCARD/ :
    {
         libc.a ( * )
         libm.a ( * )
         libgcc.a ( * )
     }

     .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
        
    
    
}
```

So why the adress stored in the isr_vector_table is 08000009 and not 08000008?
The only way I so far could change it to the right value was through hardcoding the value or defining a extra section for the Reset_Handler so I could use the adress as another extern value like the _stack_top.

Here are the commands I used for compilation as I don't know if they are necessary to find an answer:

```
cd C:/bare_metal
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -g main.c -o blink.elf -Wall -T STM32F4.ld -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb --specs=nosys.specs -nostdlib -O0
arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe -D blink.elf
```

Comment: asked and answered many times on this site.

Comment: If you peek at the default reset ISR likely found in some start-up code delivered with the tool, does it come with some peculiar "calling convention" declaration? `.thumb_set` or `.thumb_func` etc.

Comment: note that you really dont want your bootstrap written in C.  At least it is far easier to have the vector table and bootstrap in asm.

Comment: And the vendor provides one. I don't understand why you're trying to write a new one from the scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Programming Manual PM0214 of STM32F4:

> **Vector table**
> The vector table contains the reset value of the stack
> pointer, and the start addresses, also called exception vectors, for
> all exception handlers. Figure 11 on page 39 shows the order of the
> exception vectors in the vector table. The least-significant bit of
> each vector must be 1, indicating that the exception handler is Thumb
> code.

So, the LSb = 1 indicates that the instruction pointed by that vector is a *Thumb* instruction. Cortex-M cores support only *Thumb* instruction set. The compiler knows that, and makes LSb = 1 automatically. If you somehow manage to make it 0, it won't work.