# Disassembled arm code seems to have off by one error

Tags: c, arm, embedded, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I'm compiling some test code for an embedded ARM chip using a test C file.

`test.c` is as follows:

```
int main(){
  *(int*)0xFFFFF400 = 7;
}
```

I compile the file with the following command

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -march=armv4 -mtune=arm7tdmi -specs=nosys.specs -Wall -o test test.c
```

Which compiles without complaint, then I examine the assembly with

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d ./test
```

Which produces a long output with the following `main()` section:

```
00008018 <main>:
    8018:       e3e03000        mvn     r3, #0
    801c:       e3a02007        mov     r2, #7
    8020:       e3a00000        mov     r0, #0
    8024:       e5032bff        str     r2, [r3, #-3071]        ; 0xfffff401
    8028:       e1a0f00e        mov     pc, lr
```

Why does it say 0xfffff401 instead of 0xfffff400? Why is it subtracting 3071 instead of 3072?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why this function does point to itself with a offset of 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65884094/why-this-function-does-point-to-itself-with-a-offset-of-1)

Comment: Maybe? My instinct says that's a different thing though... This isn't a jump instruction it's a memory store instruction. Also this has nothing to do with thumb instructions, it's clearly a 32-bit ARM instruction that's being executed

Comment: The `mvn` instruction writes the bitwise inverse of its operand to a register. The bitwise inverse of 0 is all 1 bits, which, in two’s complement, represents −1. Then the address `[r3, #-3071]` is −1 + −3071 = −3072.

Comment: If it isn't related to thumb mode then maybe you've managed to make the compiler believe this is Linux kernel code or similar. Linux specifically uses a system where MSB set in the address means kernel code. That could explain why, though since this is physical addresses (right?) rather than virtual, it doesn't make any sense. Is there any intricate MMU setup or such?

Comment: No. Eric's answer is clearly the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mvn` instruction writes the bitwise inverse of its operand to a register. The bitwise inverse of 0 is all 1 bits, which, in two’s complement, represents −1. Then the address `[r3, #-3071]` is −1 + −3071 = −3072.

I do not know why the compiler is choosing to base its addressing off −1 rather than 0.